# C# Sqlite query response to list

Tags: c#, sqlite, arraylist

```
string query = "SELECT date(EDate,'utc'),Tag,Valuex,Note from collections where Account_Number = '1010011' AND Edate >= '2021-01-01'";
    
        using (SQLiteCommand insertCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader dr = insertCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var newentry = new List<Values>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    newentry.Add(new Values()
                    {
                        Date = dr["EDate"].ToString(),
                        Tag = dr["Tag"].ToString(),
                        Value = dr["Valuex"].ToString(),
                        Note = dr["Note"].ToString(),
                    });
                }
                dr.Close();
                Closeconnection();
                return newentry;
            }
        }
```

getting following error on the above code

Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll
Error System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I don't think `date(EDate,'utc')` returns an column with name "Edate". Try changing your sql to `date(EDate,'utc') as EDate`

Comment: Just a note, be careful how you dynamically create your query, if you let the user enter the `Account_Number` you will have a SQL Injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

you're reading 'EDate' with `dr["EDate"]` and it does not exist in the Query you need to add it to your select statement!

`string query = "SELECT date(EDate,'utc') as EDate, Tag, Valuex, Note from collections where Account_Number = '1010011' AND Edate >= '2021-01-01'";`